# Way to assign multiple files to set variable names?

Tags: file, matlab, user-interface, variables

Is there a way to assign file names to set varibles using a GUI?  Say I have 6 file sets which contain 4 colors each (blue, green, nir, red). There are 24 files in total, so i'd need 24 variables.  And I want the set varialbes to be something like

```
blue1
green1
nir1
red1

blue2
green2
nir2
red2

etc...
```

Currently I'm trying to use GUIDE to creat a custom GUI that will allow the user to select the files they wish and have them assigned to certain variables.  I am thinking something along the lines of having 24 popupmenus that are attached to a file directory and allows the user to select which file they want, and then it will assign that file and it's path to a variable (blue1 for example)  I also want 24 check boxes to associate with an if statement

Let's say popupmenu1 is associated with the variable blue1 and checkbox1

`if checkbox1 == checked`

`do import`

`elseif checkbox1 == unchecked`

`fill with zeros`

I have the basic frame of the GUI created, I am just unclear on how to apply the file select and then associate the if statements, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the variable files in advance, it's [bad practice](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/03/08/top-10-matlab-code-practices-that-make-me-cry/1/) (look also [here](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_it_advised_to_avoid_using_the_.22eval.22_function.3F) and [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html)) to use string defined variable names like this:

```
var1name = 'blue';
var2name = 'red';
% etc.

% load data
datablue=rand(4,1);
datared =rand(4,1);

% assign
eval([var1name '1 = datablue(1);']);
eval([var2name '1 = datared (1);']);
% etc.
eval([var1name '2 = datablue(2);']);
eval([var2name '1 = datared (2);']);
% etc
```

It's much easier and better to just use an ordinary array, given the variable name is not changing or application dependend, which in my example I already have as `datablue` and `datared`.

Another option if you'd like user defined variable names is to use an `array of structs`:

```
var1name = 'blue';
var2name = 'red';
sample(1).(var1name) = datablue(1);
sample(1).(var2name) = datared (1);
% ...
sample(2).(var1name) = datablue(2);
sample(2).(var2name) = datared (2);
```

Try some of these out, and only if you have a very good reason, resort to `eval`!

Answer (score 0):

```
for k = 1:6
blue(k) = sprintf('blue%d', k);
green(k) = sprintf('green%d', k);
nir(k) = sprintf('nir%d', k);
red(k) = sprintf('red%d', k);
end
```

This will create the variable names for you. Then you can use assignin (i believe) or eval to set the values to the variable names.